# How I can add a column count total to my oracle view based on rows values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an oracle view with this structure

```
--------------------
Column 1 | Column 2|
---------|---------
B        |   TEST  |
--------------------
A        |   ATEE  |
--------------------
B        |   TEST  |
--------------------   
A        |   TEST  |
--------------------
C        |   TEST  |  
--------------------
```

I wan to add an new column that hold the total of values of column 1 like this  :

```
--------------------------
Column 1 | Column 2|TOTAL |
---------|---------|------|
B        |   TEST  | 2    |
-------------------|------|
A        |   ATEE  | 2    |
-------------------|------|
B        |   TEST  | 2    |
-------------------|------|   
A        |   TEST  | 2    |
-------------------|------|
C        |   TEST  | 1    |  
-------------------|------|
```

How I can do this count ,thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want the `count()` window function:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by column1) as total
from t;
```